# Get Port Number for Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, installation, nsis

I am having fun creating my first NSIS installer:

1. Aborts if 32bit
2. Checks for a JRE - installs if not
3. Option to install Tomcat (embedded installer)
4. Option to deploy WARs (potentially this could be in the above Tomcat or another instance on the same box)

(*[Here](http://pastebin.com/BxiWCykU) is the entire script if need be.*)

I am thinking of using `ReadRegStr` to try and present the user with a list of available Tomcat instances.

However, what I was hoping to do...

**Conundrum**:
At the end of the NSIS script, I wanted to dump some shortcuts on the Desktop with links to the application that gets deployed under Tomcat.

However, from registry entries alone, I cannot get at the port number.
What is the best approach here?  I imagine I need to dive into a config file under the Tomcat folder or is their a simpler way?

[image]

[Slightly related Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708226/port-availabilty-check-on-remote-system)

Comment: You might want to add some tomcat related tags or ask the tomcat people what the official way to get the port number is. At this point the question has nothing to do with NSIS...

Answer (score 0):

You can write the command to list out the ports(netstat -a or any other command) in a test.bat file and execute it during installation using the  below command

ExecCMD::Exec $PLUGINSDIR\test.bat
This will open the command prompt and list the details of the ports.
Note: you require the plugin to execute .bat files in NSIS